# Get all output from a job utilizing matrix strategy

Tags: github, matrix, github-actions

I am going to have 2 jobs, the first job will be utilizing matrix strategy that generates different results on parallel, while the second one which can be another matrix-strategy-supported one will depend on the first and be using the outputs of it.

The problem is: how can we get all the outputs of the parallel matrix strategy job?